# Can hernia be cured without surgery using hernica sachets?

Tags: medical-science

This Indian retailer of [Hernica sachets](https://www.grocare.com/diagnose/hernica) claims they can cure hernias without surgery only using Ayurvedic ingredients.

> **Heal Hernia Without Surgery**
> We care for you much more than you care for yourself. We show this
> by specially crafting Hernica as per your needs. No one likes to get operated on.
> With Hernica, we make sure you won’t ever have to.

The [active ingredients](https://www.grocare.com/products/hernica/contents) are:

> Pongamia glabra helps to relieve Bloating and is useful in Piles and Haemorrhoids.
>
> Cassia angustifolia is known to treat Constipation. It helps promotes Peristalsis, or the regular contractions that aid bowel movements.
>
> Holarrhena antidysenterica has Astringent, Anti- dysenteric, Anthelmintic properties. It is a natural Stomachic, Febrifuge and Tonic. It is useful in treatment of Piles and Haemorrhoids. It is also known to treat Bleeding stools.
>
> Ferula asafoetida helps to strengthen Intestines. It is a Digestive, Antispasmodic and Carminative. It is very effective against Colic problems and Constipation with flatulence (gas).

Is there evidence to support this?

Comment: When an internal part of the body pushes through a weakness or protrusion in the muscle or surrounding tissue wall, it is known as hernia. Operative surgical procedures are sometimes needed for that occurrence . However, the ingredients mentioned here are claimed to treat bloating, constipation, piles, haemorrhoids and colic problems which seem to be unrelated to the actual hernia!